# How to convert image to base64 before upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

I need to post an image using AJAX, but IE does not support it. So I would like to know if I can convert the image to base64 using javascript and then post that to the php script which will then decode it and save it as an image.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can upload files via AJAX even in IE.

Comment: [JavaScript File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) is still under development...

Comment: Okay, I used the ajaxForm plugin to asynchronously post the form data to the server, but it only works in chrome an FF, It doesn't post if viewed in IE

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using JS to transform in a base64, use the enctype on the form :

```
<form action="your_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```